# No symbols loaded while debugging the .diagsession file of snapshot

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights, snapshot

I developed .NET Core Web API application using VS2017, for that I configured the application insights along with snapshot debugging feature.

I am able to see the debug snapshots in Azure Application Insights resource and download the snapshot then open it in VS2017. After that I debug **.diagsession** snapshot in VS2017 then I am getting the below error.

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.pdb contains the debug information
>   required to find the source for the module
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

[image]

I followed this blog but my issue still be there. [Issue: Symbols do not load when I open a Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-apps-troubleshooting#issue-symbols-do-not-load-when-i-open-a-snapshot)

How to resolve this error?